# How to import component from another project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, rollup

I have few components with redux store / material ui theme / api integrated in one react app called A. I want to import one of components from A to other projects (separate react app) B and C.

If I don't publish to npm, I thought best approach is build and pack to .tgz file the project A and import this file to project B and C and use like a library, but it didn't go well.

1. Could you tell me if it is a right approach?
2. Is it better to use webpack or  rollup?
3. Could you tell me how to export multiple components with redux store and api integrated? Because app.ts file is only one file which wrap the entire app with providers right? If I am exporting multiple components, what will be the way to export them with provider wrapper...?

Project A, B, C are using react with typescript, and material ui.

The reason why my approach failed was that I was using webpack to build and when it builds, there was no type definition files created. So I installed rollup and built, some files were having trouble to create definition files like reducers.. and failed.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to ensure that project A is configured as a module so you can use it. See [Create Node.Js Modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules).

When the above condition is met you can proceed with doing an NPM install as follows:

```
npm install --save ../your-local-repo
```

You could also do this in your package.json in the dependencies object:

```
"module/projectname": "file:yourmoduledirectory"
```

You could go to this link [NPM Link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to read up on how to use the link feature of NPM to link your local project to another project.

Comment: When importing a react component like this, I'm getting `Module parse failed: Unexpected token`

Comment: @codejockie how to import and use a component after saving the module? Can you please help with an example?

Comment: @Fayaz to import a module you can do this in two ways, ES6 and commonJS.
ES6: `import moduleName from "module"` - default export
ES6: `import { functionName } from "module"` - named export

commonJS: `const moduleName = require("module")` - default export
commonJS: `const { functionName } = require("module")` - named export

Comment: @codejockie, thanks for the response. I followed the steps in your answer and tried importing/using a component, but it is giving "Module not found" error. More details in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72360312/react-module-not-found-when-importing-component-from-a-local-project